# Program is seen as a virus

Tags: c, windows, memory, realloc, antivirus

I'm trying to understand how to work with `realloc` on Windows.

So I read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/realloc?view=vs-2019), copied the code into VSCode and modified it a little bit. Now I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
   long * buffer;
   long * tmp;
   size_t size;

   buffer = malloc(1000 * sizeof(long));

    // ERROR
    if(buffer == NULL)
      exit(1);
    // ERROR

   tmp = realloc(buffer, size + (1000 * sizeof(long)));

   if(tmp == NULL) {
       free(buffer);
        exit( 1 );
   }

   free(tmp);
   exit(0);
}
```

But if I compile it with `gcc`, Windows Defender says that it's a virus and deletes its execution file. Now I'm interested in why Windows Defender thinks that this is a virus. Do you have an idea what the reason might be?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you use `size` without initialization. You also don't need (and shouldn't) include `<malloc.h>`.

Comment: Variable `size` has an arbitrary (undefined) value. Function `realloc` attempts to either enlarge the current buffer if the memory block where it is allocated has enough space for the expansion, or move it to another location in memory where enough space is available and return a pointer to that location. If `size` has a huge value, and depending or other environment factors, then the attempt to expand a buffer to this huge size, *could* be seen as destructive behavior.  However, initialize `size` properly, and try again.

Comment: My AV would warn me about my own code (and Windows Defender went so far as to delete them) with no faults or exploit weaknesses. It just sees every executable it does not know about as a threat. I configured it to isolate a folder to work on. In fact Windows Defender deleted *all* my own executable code files when I moved to Windows 10, even without me running them, thanks MS.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your hints guys :) btw sorry for the late answer